# Understanding MSBuild: Printing a variable value

Tags: build, msbuild, csproj

I have following `Import` in a .csproj file. How can I find the value of `Variable` at this point of props?

```
<Import Project="<path_to_abc>\$(Variable)\abc.props>"
        Condition=" '$(Variable)' != '' "       
/>
```

I get build error:

> can not find props files : `<path_to_abc>\\abc.props`

How can I see the value of `Variable` here? If I put `Message` in the .csproj file above `Import`, what Target dependency should I give?

```
<Target Name="PrintInfo" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
   <Message Text="'$(Variable)' $(Variable.length) " />
</Target>
```

gives me `'' 0`.

But is that because of `BeforeBuild`?

How does MSBuild work?
Does it process all properties before and in the first come first order?
And then if it processes the `Targets`, does it print the value at the current time?

How can I see what values are put in while evaluating the props?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly the imports aren't currently logged, but this is about to change with the upcoming MSBuild 15.3 release and its binary logging feature.

A call to MSBuild using `/flp:Verbosity=diagnostic` will emit property reassignment events to an `msbuild.log` file like this:

```
0>Property reassignment: $(Foo)="bar" (previous value: "foo") at /Users/martin.ullrich/tmp/test.proj (10,5)
```

The log will then contain an `Initial Properties` list with the project's fully evaluated properties (including imports).

It is essential to understand that the statements property definition and import statements are processed **in order** so when an `<Import>` uses a property - either in a condition or the project path - it will use the value of the property at that moment.

There are a few other important aspects:

- Property groups are processed **before** item groups and item definition groups. Even across all imported projects! (so an `<ItemGroup>` with a condition will see the values of properties defined/imported afterwards)

  - See *[Property and Item evaluation order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997067.aspx#Anchor_2)*
- Target conditions are evaluated at the time the target is considered for execution and may be affected by both all imported project files and modifications that happened in other targets that already ran.

  - See *[Target Build Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee216359.aspx)*